# Achieve better URL structure?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have been having some issues figuring out how to have a clean URL structure for my website.
Using `.htaccess seems` to be the key, but I can't seem to use it properly.

Basically, my website is organized as follows :

```
Homepage
Gallery / Sample
About
```

Regarding file structure, the `index.html` (homepage) is located at the root.  Gallery and About are in a folder named "html" within the root.  Sample is in a folder named "samples" within "html".  The reason for it is just to avoid having all html files and have better organization, but that might be the source of my issue.

So if I go to my gallery, the URL will look like `www.domain.com/html/gallery.html`.

And if I go to the sample within the gallery, the URL will look like `www.domain.com/html/samples/sample.html`.

My goal is that, when I go to my gallery, the URL looks like `www.domain.com/gallery`.

And when I go to the sample within the gallery, the URL looks like `www.domain.com/gallery/sample`.

I have been reading a few tutorials about `.htaccess` and URL Rewriting, all I managed to do is break the link to my gallery (leads to a 404).  Apparently URL rewriting is for actually redirecting, and not changing the URL's structure.

Does anyone know how I could proceed to do this?

It would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may help - [Introduction To URL Rewriting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Comment: This is one of the tutorials I followed earlier that lead me to get error 404s.  I probably missed something, so I'm gonna take another look at it.  Thanks.